# RSpec No route matches for destroy method

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to test create method for my app but I am getting the following error:

```
1) RanksController POST #create when user is sign in creates rank
   Failure/Error: post :create, params: { user: user, movie: movie }

ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"ranks", :movie=>#<Movie 
id: 1, title: "excepturi", description: "Vilicus crur volutabrum balbus cum 
vulgaris statua...", released_at: "1998-03-22 00:00:00", avatar: nil, 
genre_id: 1, created_at: "2019-01-15 14:45:10", updated_at: "2019-01-15 
14:45:10">, :user=>#<User id: 1, email: "deja@ruel.co", created_at: "2019- 
01-15 14:45:10", updated_at: "2019-01-15 14:45:10", phone_number: name: "">}
```

I found a lot of potential solutions but they did not work for me.

ranks_controller_spec

```
RSpec.describe RanksController, type: :controller do
  let(:user) { FactoryBot.create(:user) }
  let(:movie) { FactoryBot.create(:movie) }

  describe "POST #create" do
    context "when user is sign in" do
      before { sign_in(user) }

      it "creates rank" do
        expect do
          post :create, params: { user: user, movie: movie }
        end.to change(Rank, :count).by(1)
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:redirect)
      end
    end
  end
```

ranks_controller

```
  class RanksController < ApplicationController
       before_action :set_movie, only: %i[create destroy]

       def create
         Rank.create!(user: current_user, movie: @movie)

         redirect_to @movie
       end

       def destroy
         rank = @movie.ranks.find(params[:id])
         rank.destroy!

         redirect_to @movie
       end

       private

       def set_movie
         @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
       end
     end
```

show.html.haml

```
  - if @rank
       = link_to 'Vote', movie_rank_path(@movie, @rank), method: :delete
     - else
       = link_to 'Vote', movie_ranks_path(@movie), method: :post
```

show action in movies_controller.rb:

```
  def show
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    @like = @movie.likes.find_by(user: current_user)
  end
```

routes.rb

```
 resources :movies, only: [:index, :show] do
   resources :ranks, only: %i[create destroy]
   member do
     get :send_info
   end
   collection do
     get :export
   end
 end
```

In a web version everything works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass id instead of object like following

```
post :create, params: { user_id: user.id, movie_id: movie.id }
```

I think you don't need to pass `user` or `user_id` at all since you are not using it on create action. `current_user` on create action should return the user you are signing in on `before` block.